# setting a cell to the sum product formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a issue with this not selecting the correct range to form the formula and I can not figure out why.

```
Set R11 = Cells(7, 18)
Set R12 = Cells(LastRow - 1, LastColumn - 1)
Set R21 = Cells(7, LastColumn + 2)
Set R22 = Cells(LastRow - 1, LastCol2 - 1)
Set Fcell = Cells(6, LastCol2)

Fcell.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(" & R11 & ":" & R12 & "," & R21 & ":" & R22 & ")"
```

Comment: Where are you setting `LastColumn` and `LastRow`? If that isn't the problem, you should be using something more like `R11.Address` if you want to use it in a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set R11 = Cells(7, 18)
Set R12 = Cells(LastRow, LastColumn - 1)
Set R21 = Cells(7, LastColumn + 2)
Set R22 = Cells(LastRow, LastCol2 - 1)
Set Fcell = Cells(6, LastCol2)

Fcell.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(" & R11.Address & ":" & R12.Address & "," & R21.Address & ":" & R22.Address & ")"
```

Comment: IS this the answer to your own question? If true, then mark it as answered

Comment: It wont let me. I have to wait 2 days